# filepond image preview plugin is creating infinite scroll on the page

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, filepond

I am using filepong to handle fileuploads. I am using its [image preview](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/plugins/image-preview/) plugin to show image previews.

Here is how I am attaching the filepond to my input

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/filepond.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{ asset('js/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/filepond.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>

    FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);

    // Select the file input and use create() to turn it into a pond
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"].filepond');
    const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

    // Create a FilePond instance
    const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
        onaddfile: (error, file) => {
            if (!error) {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image', file.file);

                // Make an AJAX request to your Livewire component method
                // Adjust the URL and method as per your Livewire component setup
                //Livewire.emit('storeImages', JSON.stringify(pond.getFiles()));
            }
        },
    });

    pond.setOptions({
        server: {
            process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort, transfer, options) => {
                // fieldName is the name of the input field
                // file is the actual file object to send
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name);

                const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                request.open('POST', '{{route('event.images.store')}}');

                // Should call the progress method to update the progress to 100% before calling load
                // Setting computable to false switches the loading indicator to infinite mode
                request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
                    progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
                };

                request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken)

                // Should call the load method when done and pass the returned server file id
                // this server file id is then used later on when reverting or restoring a file
                // so your server knows which file to return without exposing that info to the client
                request.onload = function () {
                    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {

                        window.Livewire.emit('uploadedFilePaths', request.response)

                        // the load method accepts either a string (id) or an object
                        load(request.responseText);
                    } else {
                        // Can call the error method if something is wrong, should exit after
                        error('oh no');
                    }
                };

                request.send(formData);

                // Should expose an abort method so the request can be cancelled
                return {
                    abort: () => {
                        // This function is entered if the user has tapped the cancel button
                        request.abort();

                        // Let FilePond know the request has been cancelled
                        abort();
                    },
                };
            },
        },
        allowMultiple: true,
    });

   
</script>
<style>
    .filepond--root.filepond.filepond--hopper {
        width: 50% !important;
    }
</style>
```

As soon as image finishes uploading, an height of the div starts increasing that is used for the preview and it keeps increasing infinitely unless i reload the page.

Not sure whats going wrong.